# About Regex matches

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'll warn you all since from the beginning: I'm a beginner on Regular Expressions. With that in mind lets begin and I'm using C++ Deelx library.

I have this text to pass in my regex:

```
char tempStr[] = "Ésta è À ç À Ária õ ûma CÓïSSSê";
```

My intention is to remove all occurencies of accented characters. Reading about regex on the very good site:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html

I made this expression to replace all occurencies of uppercase accented "A":

```
//^\b.*(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)\b.*$
```

For my surprise it didn't work. My understading of this expression is: "Search in the whole string, zero or more occurencies of these characters".

Now when I use this expression the job is done perfectly:

```
(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)
```

What makes me wonder is: I didn't determined nothing instead a set of chars neither number of occurencies and works, and in the first case nothing occurs. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
^\b.*(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)\b.*$
```

says look for:

- the start of the string (`^`)
- followed by a word boundary (`\b`)
- followed by any character none or multiple times (`.*`)
- followed by a ONE of the uppercase accented A's (`(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)`)
- followed by a word boundary (`\b`)
- followed by any character none or multiple times (`.*`)
- followed by the end of the string

So it will only match strings that have only one uppercase accented A.

The other regex:

```
(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)
```

says look for:

- one of the uppercase accented A's (`(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)`)

If you apply the regex globally (usually using the global flag `g`, some regex functions of some languages apply it by default), then it will execute the regex multiple times.

However, if your intention is the remove all accented characters, there might be better ways to do it than listing all the accented characters. Depening on what you want, you could for example match only the characters that you want to allow, and remove the rest.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Some other questions: For the first pattern, what I need to modify to get that characters multiple times? And what are your proposal to improve to remve all accented characters? I'm very curious.

Comment: For the first pattern to match multiple accented A's you should just add a `+` after the parenthesized list, like `^\b.*(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å)+\b.*$`. But you could maybe better write it like `^\b.*[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]+\b.*$`. To remove the accented characters you should probably use a regex replace function in your language, then match the accented characters and then replace them with an empty string. Depending on what function you use the regex could differ.